# TeamCity - MSBuild issue

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

My setup includes MSBuild version : 16, .Net.exe : 5.8.1
When I run build setup in TeamCity, I am facing this error continuously :

C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241, 5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file
project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

I have tried running `dotnet restore` and `nuget restore` command alternatively but showing me different errors. Also tried `msbuild -t:build -restore` command but it says error MSB4057: The target "build" does not exist in the project. Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What errors appeared when running the dotnet restore and nuget restore commands? Are you building off the solution file or csproj file?

Comment: Hey @JeffGruenbaum. I am applying this commands to my .sln (solution) file. And unfortunately many errors occur after this command build step which were stating *MVC* file does not exists and so on.

Comment: @aziz_Suterwala Do you have this code setup locally? I would see if you can get it to run locally before running the build on Teamcity. This may help pinpoint the problem. Part of the problem may be that there are some dependencies between the projects being built. Since you are building through the .sln file, I'm assuming multiple csproj files are being built.  I would try building each csproj individually and see if you can pinpoint the error. I would also try running the msbuild command without using the `-t:build` argument. Run `msbuild myproject.csproj -restore`.

Comment: Hey @JeffGruenbaum. Thanks for your help. I applied `NuGet installer (restore)` build first and than `msbuild`. I added an extra CLI parameter in MSBuild ( `-p:RestorePackagesConfig=true` ) which helped me to restore all my NuGet packages.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it to work!